# How to prevent Console Application from terminating when pressing "Ctrl+C" in C?

Tags: c, winapi, mingw32

I found that Console Application compiled from GCC on Windows always terminate when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Is there any feasible way to prevent Console Application from terminating when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user presses control C, a signal (SIGINT) is sent to your process. When most signals are sent to a process, that process must either handle the signal or the operating system will kill it. So... all you need to do is install a signal handler for SIGINT.

The following is untested:

```
#include <signal.h>
static void ignore_control_c(int sig)
{
    /* re-arm the signal handler but otherwise ignore the signal */
    signal(sig, ignore_control_c);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
   signal(SIGINT, ignore_control_c);
   ...
```

Comment: I have already added `#include<windows.h>`, but GCC reported that `error: 'SIGINT' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: Did you also include <signal.h>? If so, look inside and find what the label is for signal 2. I've seen some reference to suggest that mingw32 changes things and might use SIGKILL for that signal -- which is against convention. The main task is identify what signal is being received and catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Install a SIGINT Handler. By default, this handler is set to terminate your process. For windows, you can register using Win32-specific [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Have a look at the documentation linked above, and especially the example.