# How to install a hook node on the running cmd application compiled/run by Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, messaging

I need to intercept the close (WM_CLOSE) message(s) issued to my program, which is a console application i print stuff on, so i could let the program undergo cleaning-up, deallocations and destroying the Vulkan Instance (in my case).
If i were to install a hook procedure on the Win32 Messaging hook chain, I'd need the instance (HINSTANCE) of the console applications .exe module, which i guess is the same as the running code module. I'd also need the ID of the Looper Thread, that handles the messaging of the shell console application, which i couldn't find any way to obtain!?

Comment: Console applications don't get any messages as they are console not window applications.  Only applications that create windows get messages.  But as you mention Vulkan (which needs a window) the question is confusing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047228/how-to-prevent-console-application-from-terminating-when-pressing-ctrlc-in-c

Comment: How can i detect when (before) the console window app is closing, so i could cleanup the Vulkan instance.

Comment: you need call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` and you got notify in your `HandlerRoutine` say you got `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`

Comment: Thanks, i'd appreciate it if you post this comment as answer, as it helped me out.